# Fullscreen auto-restart in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, fullscreen, reboot

I got a problem with the full screen feauture on many app I use when I restart the computer.
Some apps like Safari that I leave in full screen mode when I shut down,
come back in full-screen mode also when I login again, but some others apps like Chrome does not.

I want those app to remain full-screen and not have to click the arrows every time I restart the Mac.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can do to fix this directly (unless you can [develop a fix yourself](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)).  What you're seeing is a bug in those applications' full-screen support.  Hopefully, it will be fixed eventually!

To speed the process for e.g. Chrome, [report an issue to the Chrome product team using the *Report an issue* feature](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2a2135b6f50fd524).  The same goes for the other products with which you're seeing this behavior - find a way to contact their makers/developers to report the issue.

Comment: Yes but it's really weird, because I just reinstalled Lion, the same version, and before reinstalling I hadn't this problem neither with Chrome... before reinstalling, it all works.. So I thought there have to be some kinds of settings to change.. but I can't figure it out..

Comment: That is odd. It's possible that it's a new bug - since Chrome auto-updates in the background, this might be correlated with (but not caused by) your OS reinstall.

Out of curiosity, why reinstall?  Also, the bug DB is at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/

Comment: Well, I reinstalled a fresh copy because suddenly, some days ago, the OS begin to take a very long time to become ready from when I turn it on.. like more than 10 minutes!